# clipspy installing fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'clips.h': No such file or directory

Tags: clips, clipspy

i'm trying to install clipspy on Python 3.8 but i get this error

`fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'clips.h': No such file or directory`

i've tried installing previous versions of clipspy but didn't work

thanks to everybody will answer

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: i'm using windows 10 pro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: `clipspy` 0.3.3 builds for Python 3.8 have been released.

You can give it a try now.

Comment: How did you install it?